# CSS-Add round status button on top of another

Tags: html, css

I am new to css. How can I add a status button which changes color depending on chat availability on top of another button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `position` property.

See an example code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ygz2ev3/).

Some resources:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you Tugrul Gungor, your method was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

From the picture i can tell you don't have to use 2 html elements on top of each other, but you can use css properties like border and background-color to achieve exactly as the button in your picture.

I posted how in the code below with even a little bit of javascript to toogle the button status (not needed for styling, so if you don't know any javascript yet, you can skip that part).

```js
let isOpen = false;
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const dot = document.querySelector(".dot");
const txt = document.querySelector("#text");


btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (isOpen) {
    dot.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    txt.innerHTML = "The chat is now closed";
  } else {
    dot.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    txt.innerHTML = "The chat is now open";
  }
  isOpen = !isOpen;
});
```

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid gray;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <p id="text">The chat is now closed</p>
</div>

<button id="btn">Toogle</button>
```